# Iterating over a powerset with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a generator for a powerset of a list in python and I want do some calculations to the elements of these set using the multiprocessing module. My code looks like:

```
def powerset(seq): 
  '''Returns all the subsets of the list. This is a generator.'''
  if len(seq) == 0:
    yield seq
  if len(seq) == 1:
    yield seq 
    yield []
  elif len(seq) > 1: 
    for item in powerset(seq[1:]):
      yield [seq[0]]+item
      yield item

def job(l):
  # do some calculation with the list l
  return do_some_hard_work(l)

def calculate():
  pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size, maxtasksperchild=2)
  pool_outputs = pool.map(job, powerset(list(range(1,10)))
  pool.close()
  pool.join()

  return sum(pool_outputs)
```

The problem is that the powerset-function is a generator and that will not work. But I can not replace the generator, because of generate the hole powerset before the calculation needs to much time and memory. Has anyone an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: _"a generator and that will not work"_ From what I can see on a small list, it provides the desired answer. What is "not working" ?

Comment: You're allowed to pass a generator to `pool.map`, just know that it will be converted to a list prior to any items being sent to worker processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is that you want to avoid having to put the whole powerset in a list, you can use [`pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap), which will consume your iterator `chunksize` elements at a time, and send those off to the worker processes, rather than converting the whole thing into a list and chunking that up.

```
pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size, maxtasksperchild=2)
pool_outputs = pool.imap(job, powerset(list(range(1,10))), chunksize=<some chunksize>)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

If your powerset is very large, you'll want to specify a `chunksize` other than the default, which is 1:

> The chunksize argument is the same as the one used by the map()
>   method. For very long iterables using a large value for chunksize can
>   make the job complete much faster than using the default value of 1.

The `map` function uses the following algorithm, to give you an idea of a good size:

```
chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(pool_size) * 4)
if extra:
    chunksize += 1
```